# Does it load the data from database?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Assume we have a method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FirstMethod()
{
    var entities = from t in context.Products
                   where {some conditions}
                   select t;

    foreach( var entity in entities )
    {
        entity.SomeProperty = {SomeValue};
        yield return entity;   
    }
}
```

where context is a DataContext that is generated by Linq to SQL designer.

Does "FirstMethod" load the data into memory from database (because of the foreach loop) or will it still defer-load it until another foreach loop that doesn't have "yield return" is found in another method like the following?

```
public void SecondMethod()
{
    foreach( var item in FirstMethod() )
    {
        {Do Something}
    }
}
```

Comment: (updated re your comment; added here for visibility)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latter (deferred); `FirstMethod` is an iterator block (because of `yield return`); this means that you have a chain of iterators. Nothing is read until the **final caller** starts iterating the data; then each record is read in turn during the **final caller's** `foreach` (between which the connection/command is open).

The `using` that surrounds `foreach` (under the bonnet) ensures that the connection is closed if the `foreach` is abandoned half-way-through.

If you **want** to load the data earlier, use `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to buffer the data locally - but note that this breaks "composition" - i.e. the caller can no longer add extra `Where` etc clauses (which they can if it returns a raw `IQueryable<T>`).

---

Re your question:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FirstMethod()
{
    var entities = from t in context.Products
                   where {some conditions}
                   select t;

    foreach( var entity in entities.AsEnumerable() )
    {
        entity.SomeProperty = {SomeValue};
        yield return entity;   
    }
}
```

The `AsEnumerable` is the key here; it ends the composable `IQueryable<T>` chain, and uses LINQ-to-Objects for the rest.

Comment: You learn something new every day, I guess. I'll delete my answer :P

Comment: I've checked the data context log and it seems that other linq clauses will not translate to SQL commands. Is there any way to this? All I want is to set a property (that is not a column) when the result set returns from an IQueryable<T> method.

Answer (score 2):

In short, it doesn't load until SecondMethod performs the iteration...

Read [here](http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-systemlinqwhere-really-works.html) for more...

Answer (score 1):

Loading is deferred until the **GetEnumerator** method is called on the **entities** query and that won't happen until the **GetEnumerator** method is called on the **IEnumerable<T>** you're returning.